# Deriving the equation for the probability of a prime number

Tags: probability, prime-numbers

A couple of months ago I stumbled upon an equation regarding the probability of having a prime number adjacent to "x". If I remember correctly it was:
$\frac {x}{ln x}$ ,or something along those lines.

It puzzled me at the time but I didn't give it much though, now, however, I have stumbled upon it again and I can't seem to comprehend from were was this derived. Furthermore, what is the relationship between $\ln x$ and a prime number (pardon my low comprehension on the subject, I take it must be a fairly simple relation).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The prime number theorem says (loosely) that the prime counting function is $\pi(n) \approx \frac{n}{\log n}$, which is almost certainly where this comes from.